# How do I send multiple returned values in an email?

Tags: excel, vba

The objective is to send an email with all values the code returns.

The output is the last value instead of all values in the email.

```vb
Sub Email()

Dim Outlook, OutApp, OutMail As Object
Dim EmailSubject As String, EmailSendTo As String, MailBody As String
Dim SigString As String, Signature As String, fpath As String
Dim Quarter As String, client() As Variant
Dim Alert As Date, Today As Date, Days As Integer, Due As Integer

Set Outlook = OpenOutlook

Quarter = Range("G4").Value
Set rng = Range(Range("G5"), Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

'Resize Array prior to loading data
ReDim client(rng.Rows.Count)

'Check column G for blank cells and return F cells
For Each Cell In rng
    If Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
        ReDim client(x)
        Alert = Cell.Offset(0, 0).Value
        Today = Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yy")
        Days = Alert - Today
        Due = Days * -1
        client(x) = Cell.Offset(0, -3).Value & " " & Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
    End If
Next
    For x = LBound(client) To UBound(client)
        List = client(x) & vbNewLine
        List = List + List
    Next x
        
'Check dates to send subject line'
    If Days < 0 Then
        mail = True
        EmailSubject = Quarter & " Vat Returns are Overdue"
        MailBody = "<p>The Vat Returns are overdue by " & Due & " Days. See the clients below: </p>" & List
    ElseIf Days <= 14 Then
        mail = True
        EmailSubject = "Vat Returns are due within Two weeks"
        MailBody = "<p>The Vat Returns are due in " & Days & " Days. See the clients below: </p>" & List
    End If
  
'Fetch signature
    SigString = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\.htm"
    Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
    
'Fetch link for file location
    fpath = "K:
    
'Skip if mail=false
    If mail = True Then
    
'Send Mail
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(o)
        With OutMail
            .Subject = EmailSubject
            .To = ""
            '.bcc
            sHTML = "<HTML><BODY>"
            sHTML = sHTML & "<p>Hi, </p>"
            sHTML = sHTML & MailBody
            sHTML = sHTML & "<p>If the Vat Return have been filed, please update the database using the link below.</p>"
            sHTML = sHTML & "<A href='" & fpath & "'></A>"
            sHTML = sHTML & "<p>Regards,</p>"
            .HTMLBody = sHTML & Signature
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "</BODY></HTML>"
            .Display
        End With
        
        Set Outlook = Nothing
        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing
        
        mail = False
        EmailSendTo = ""
        
    End If

End Sub
```

The code returns the last value in the if statement and places it in an email.

I want to run though the range of data. If the cell in column G:G is blank then return the cell value in column F:F.

I can send multiple emails to one email address with one cell value in each email.
I want to send one email with all (multiple) cell values returned.

I took out personal details but this will not affect the running of the code.

Comment: Inside the `For each Cell in rng` loop you reference `client(x)`, but `x` isn't given a value until after that loop in the `For x = lbound(client) to ubound(client)`.  By the looks of it the first use of `x` will always be 0, and then when you get to the `For x` line it will still be 0 as `client` array will have a `lbound` and `ubound` of 0.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook the value of x changes to 3 in the last loop. There is 3 values in this particular if statement. Is it possible to have all 3 values shown when it is called in the if statement (check the subject line)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the `client()` array if you build the List directly.

```vb
Today = Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yy")
For Each cell In Rng
    If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
        Alert = cell.Offset(0, 0).Value
        Days = Alert - Today
        Due = Days * -1
        If Len(List) > 0 Then List = List & vbNewLine
        List = List & cell.Offset(0, -3).Value & " " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
    End If
Next
```

Note `OutApp.CreateItem(o)` should be `OutApp.CreateItem(0)`

Comment: This works. However, the email shows up as the value 1 "space" value 2 etc.. Is it possible to have a new line after each value?

Comment: @Brendacodedotcom Use `"<br>"` in place of `vbNewLine`

Comment: Thanks. I used “<p><\p>” instead.